# How do I store large no.of small entries in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to store daily average temperature of various cities for the whole year in Mysql. I have the data. I wanted to know if there is any alternative way which will save time since the other way is very time consuming. I'm not a advance user of Mysql. Any help will be really appreaciated.

Comment: Time consuming how?

Comment: You should look into [Time Series Database](http://opentsdb.net).

Comment: Time consuming in the sense I have to make entry into the database for each day of the year for past 10 years.That seems very time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

If you are entering data from hard copy then it will be time consuming. At most, you can increase the no. of people who will be entering them.

If it is a soft copy, in form of a text file or web page or some csv file, you can extract data from them using some code and enter them in the DB. It will be much faster once you can come up with your extracting code.